Are these different constructions of Rindler vacuum equivalent?
In a Minkowski spacetime and for a Klein-Gordon field, I have seen two different constructions of the Rindler vacuum in different references, but they don't seem to be equivalent.
The first construction is in Ref.[1] Sec. 9.5. Following Ref.[1], the metric in Rindler coordinates is
\begin{equation}
d s^2=e^{2 a \xi}\left(-\mathrm{d} \eta^2+\mathrm{d} \xi^2\right).
\end{equation}
The positive frequency modes are associated to the timelike killing vector $\partial_\eta$, and take the form (in region I, see [1] for details)
\begin{equation}
g_k^{(1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi \omega}} e^{-i \omega \eta+i k \xi},
\end{equation}
with a correspondent annihilation operator such that
\begin{equation}
\hat{b}_k^{(1)}\left|0_{\mathrm{R}}\right\rangle=0,
\end{equation}
where $\left|0_{\mathrm{R}}\right\rangle$ is denoted Rindler vacuum.
On the other hand, in Ref.[2] Sec. 4.3.1 they consider the null coordinates \begin{equation}
v \equiv  \eta +\xi, u \equiv \eta -\xi
\end{equation}
and take as positive frequency modes
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\vec{X}_w^R & \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi w}} e^{-i w u}, \\
\stackrel{\leftarrow}{X}_w^R & \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi w}} e^{-i w v}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Does the choice of these two different observers result in different definitions of Rindler vacuum?
[1] Carroll, S. M. (2019). Spacetime and Geometry. https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108770385
[2] Fabbri, A., & Navarro-Salas, J. (2005). Modeling Black Hole Evaporation. https://doi.org/10.1142/9781860947223

I can't say for sure, but I think they might be equivalent after all, because the notion of "time" still looks the same. I think if you take the Fourier transform with respect to $\eta$ of the second set of modes you will find that positive frequency with respect to $\eta$ is positive frequency with respect to the null times
